# Disappear data after refresh in Vuejs SPA

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex, vue-router

I use **Vuex** and load my data in some cards in a page, when I click on any card it goes to another route that load full data of that card, it's work fine and data will shown, BUT, when i refresh my page data will disappear!!

code:

```
import {mapState} from 'vuex'

export default {
    name: 'JoInfo',
    data () {
        return {
            joInfo: []
        }
    },
    mounted () {
        this.joInfo = this.jobOpening.find(obj => obj.id == this.$route.params.jo_address)
        console.log(this.joInfo)

        this.$store.dispatch('LOAD_JO')
    },
    computed: {
        ...mapState(['jobOpening'])
    }
}
```

Comment: That is because when moving from one route to another on a SPA, the state is persisted. Refreshing the page will destroy whatever that you previously had: therefore, you will need to find a way to persist that state, using either localStorage or sessionStorage. There are several plugins out there that can persist VueX stores for you.

Comment: Thanks @Terry , So I think **vuex-persistedstate** will help me

Comment: either [vuex-persistedstate](https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate) or just plain js implementation of localstorage/indexeddb will do